# how to get image from json and display it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I get the photo address from the backend with json, but how to set it as a src image and show this image?

```
 $.post(               
       "{%url 'validate_email' %}",
         {
           email: $("#members_email").val()
         },
          function (data, status) {
              console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data) + " " + status);
          }
       );
```

output in console:

```
Data: {"user_avatar":"/media/mizbanuser/profile_img/2020-10- 
        27_095908.3275338039170.jpg","status":true} success
```

Comment: you have your photo url.... just add you host / origin. localhost or domain www.mysite.com/media/mizbanuser/profile....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function createIMG (data, status) {
  var img = document.createElement('img')
  img.setAttribute("src", data.user_avatar);
  document.body.appendChild(img)
}

//simulate the input:
createIMG({"user_avatar":"/media/mizbanuser/profile_img/2020-10- 27_095908.3275338039170.jpg","status":true}, 'success')
```

You can change `document.body` to `document.getElementById('<insert parent element here>')` if you want to add it to a specific element. The 2nd line creates the element, the 3rd sets the src, and the fourth puts the element inside body. In the end your code should look like:

```js
 $.post(               
       "{%url 'validate_email' %}",
         {
           email: $("#members_email").val()
         },
          function (data, status) {
              var img = document.createElement('img')
              img.setAttribute("src", data.user_avatar);
              document.body.appendChild(img)
          }
       );
```

Or if you want to check for success first:

```js
 $.post(               
       "{%url 'validate_email' %}",
         {
           email: $("#members_email").val()
         },
          function (data, status) {
              if (status == 'success') {
                  var img = document.createElement('img')
                  img.setAttribute("src", data.user_avatar);
                  document.body.appendChild(img)
              } else {
                  // handle error
              }
          }
       );
```